# iTerm2 Terminal Too Wide Error

Tags: macos, vi, iterm2

I am using iTerm2 to ssh to various servers.  When i use VI to edit a file i get an error that reads 'Terminal Too Wide.'  To fix this I use the following command 'stty columns 120.'  Is there a setting that I can set in iTerm that will prevent me from having to enter this command?

Comment: Use `vim` instead.

Comment: is that the only way?  i was really looking for something in iterm specifically.

Comment: You can always add the `stty` the the SSH system's shell profile so it's executed automatically. But vi simply cannot handle more columns, unless you patch and compile it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make the terminal window too wide (e.g. fullscreen). Both Terminal and iTerm make the terminal as wide as the window can handle by default to not waste screen space. Unfortunately, `vi` doesn't appear to handle more than a *hardcoded* number of columns (`160`, currently).

In the [ex-vi](http://ex-vi.sourceforge.net/) source code, Release 050325, check out `config.h` line 94, and in `ex_v.c`, the `vok` function definition that produces this error.

[Some Linux distributions](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/15844) apparently patch `vi` source code to get more columns for bigger screens.